# Auto adjust margin-top of content section based on hight fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've searched all over and found plenty of "solutions" but none of them seem to work for me. I'm a newbi/amature developer.

I have a fixed header. The header is resizing when scrolling.
I know that if I put `padding-top: 100px` for example my content stays below my fixed header. But as the fixed header changes size when scrolling I want the `top-padding` of the `content` section automatically adjusted based on the size of the fixed header.

```
<header id="main-header" class="">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="navigation">
            <nav id="top-menu-nav">
                <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
                   <li> menu 1</li>
                </ul>                   
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
```

**CSS**

```
#main-header{position:fixed;z-index:99999;width:100%}
#content{position:relative}
```

No what I've tried is to put the following script in my header but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**Script**

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function(){
    var height = $('#main-header').height();
    $('#content').css({'padding-top':height});
    }).trigger('resize');
</script>
```

Comment: Use #main-header instead of .main-header in your script

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. it's #main-header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as expected. I applied the location for the header and set the margin for content instead of padding.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var height = $('#main-header').height();
  $('#content').css({
    'margin-top': height
  });
}).trigger('resize');
```

```css
#main-header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* For visibility */
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#content {
  /* For visibility */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-header" class="">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="navigation">
      <nav id="top-menu-nav">
        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
          <li> menu 1</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Comment: But the content is still behind the header.

Comment: @Wouter I put text in the content so you can see it is not behind the header

Comment: I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Where do I put the actual script? above the header?

Comment: This works fine! Thank you. The only thing I needed to do was to change the "resize" to "load"

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    headerHeight = $('#main-header').height();
    $('#content').css('padding-top' , height + 'px');
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($('#main-header').height() != headerHeight) {
        headerHeight = $('#main-header').height();
        $('#content').css('padding-top' , headerHeight + 'px');
    }
});
</script>
```

Basically it checks whenever the #header-div changes size on scroll.

Comment: No, sorry; content is still below fixed header and nothing happens.

Comment: Do need it to resize when the header div resizes? or do you need it to resize when the window is resized?

Comment: If you need the padding-top to be changed whenever the #main-header div resizes ( not the window ). Then I have a solution. So let me know. I just want to understand what you need.

Comment: The fixed header changes size when scrolling, but I want my the margin when my content section starts to be calculated based on the size of the fixed header.